# React Query refetchInterval not working, only calls API once

Tags: react-query, tanstack, tanstackreact-query

I had used [refetchInterval](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/examples/react/auto-refetching) before and it was very straightforward. For some reason I can't get it working anymore now.

This code only calls the API only once.

```
const { data, isFetching } = useQuery(
  ['test'],
  () => axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'),
  { refetchInterval: 3000 }
)
console.log('isFetching=', isFetching)
```

It prints this at the beginning

```
isFetching= true
isFetching= false
```

then only prints this every 3 seconds

```
isFetching= false
```

If I manually click the blue "Refetch" button in the reactQueryDevTool, it will also print `isFetching= false` once, without making any network call.

Why is it only making network call once in the beginning? What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I found why! This project has an axios cache set up!!